# Apache Nifi : Execute / Trigger Nifi Processor From Java Application

Tags: java, api, http, apache-flink, apache-nifi

Is it possible to **call the Apache Nifi ListenHTTP processor or HandleHttpRequest from the java application**?
Also How to send my custom arguments to ListenHTTP "Remote URL" property from a java application?

[image]

How to set properties of a Processor through Java API?

How to pass a parameter through an URL to a **Nifi processor group**? And how can I start the processor group through that URL.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/firstname/{first_name}/lastname/{last_name}
```

I want to send first_name and last_name **from my java application to Nifi processor**? 
how to achieve this?

Comment: use any rest client you like. https://www.google.com/search?q=java+rest+client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different questions here.

1. **How to interact with the `ListenHTTP` or `HandleHttpRequest` processors from a separate Java application?** - use any HTTP client from your Java application to send a request. This can be as simple as using the [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) class or [`HttpClient`](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html), or using a library like [Apache HTTP Components](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).
2. **How to send custom arguments in an HTTP request from Java?** - The links above describe this process for each approach. In general, in your Java code, you will have to construct the request (either by appending these values to the URL for a `GET` request, or forming the request body for a `POST` request).
3. **How to set properties of a NiFi processor through the API?** - You will not be able to invoke a Java method on NiFi when running from a separate Java application. You will need to use the [NiFi REST API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) to perform these actions. There are many [examples](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Using-the-NIFI-REST-API-to-execute-a-data-flow-created-in/td-p/163277) of using the REST API to do so. The NiFi UI is also a reference implementation, so you can use your browser's Developer Tools to observe and capture any action you make in the UI, as it calls the API directly.
4. **How to start a Processor Group via the API?** - The link in the previous bullet shows an example of starting a processor via the API. The process is very similar for a PG; just identify the PG via UUID instead.
5. **How to send first name and last name in the specified URL format from Java?** - The code for this depends on the existing data structure and method of connecting. I also suspect that the processor configuration being shown in your screenshot is an `InvokeHTTP` processor, not the `ListenHTTP` processor based on the available properties. If you want to send data *from* a regular Java application *to* NiFi via HTTP, you would configure your `ListenHTTP` processor to listen on a specific **port** and **base path**, and then make HTTP connections to that address. So for example, using the default base path and port 8888, an external application would make a request to `http://localhost:8888/contentListener` with request body `{"firstname": "Andy", "lastname": "LoPresto"}` in order to provide that JSON. The flowfile content would then contain those values. The `ListenHTTP` processor doesn't provide arbitrary URL parsing to extract those values from the querystring, so you would have to manually perform that logic.

Comment: Thanks, Andy . Thanks for your details.  From ListenHTTP processor I was able to received firstname and lastname . Now I want to apply this firstname and lastname to  **InvokeHttp** Processor **"Remote URL"** property. For eg.  http://localhost:9999/api/getAddressDetails/{firstname}/{lastname} .

Comment: Depending on the format of the data in your flowfile content, use `ExtractText` or `EvaluateJSONPath` to pull those values into flowfile attributes, then use Expression Language in the URL to populate them like so: `http://localhost:9999/api/getAddressDetails/${firstname}/${lastname}`,

Comment: Thanks Andy.. It's working.I was able to set firstname and lastname by using EvaluateJSONPath ->UpdateAttribute -> InvokeHTTP processor.

Comment: What role is `UpdateAttribute` performing? `EvaluateJSONPath` should extract the values out to arbitrarily named attributes itself.

Comment: Ya yes. You are right. EvaluateJSONPath  is enough. I have wrongly added the UpdateAttribute processor from some reference sites. UpdateAttribute processor is not needed.